# Compute the the dominant eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector of a sparse transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I have a sparse $N\times N$ transition matrix (asymmetric), in which most entries are zero. I can use `scipy.linalg.eig` to compute all eigenvalues and eigenvectors and then find the dominant eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector. However, if $N$ is very large, it suffers from high computational expensive.

Is there some method more space-effective for the computation of the dominant eigenvalue and its eigenvector for a sparse transition matrix?

Comment: You could use the data structures of `scipy.sparse` and the methods from `scipy.sparse.linalg`.

Comment: What does transition matrix mean in your context? Is it a transition matrix from one basis to another basis or is a left/right stochastic matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes---use the power iteration method. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) has more details, including a Python implementation.

The power iteration method requires only taking matrix-vector products, and so remains efficient for large, sparse matrices. Note though that it will find the largest-magnitude eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector (and will have numerical issues if the spectral gap between the two largest-magnitude eigenvalues is small); if you want the most-positive eigenvalue of an indefinite matrix instead, you will need to modify the algorithm a bit.